# call jquery animation from external file

Tags: jquery, mysql, animation, twitter, auto-update

my scenario is following. I want to check a mysql database every few seconds for new entries. If there is a new entry, I would like to call an animation to slide if the new database entry.

For this I'm trying to combine two good tutorials I found.

http://www.aleixcortadellas.com/main/2009/02/15/automatically-query-mysql-and-output-results-with-ajax/ (this one checks the database every five seconds)

http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/blog/scrolling-list (this one has a nice animation)

The database refresh is working fine (boo.php), but I'm having troubles to call the animation or maybe it is just a logical problem.

I think to call the animation, I need to echo out something like this from the boo.php file:

echo " smoothAdd('u10', 'text');";

I looked for some auto updating newstickers or twitter style updates, but I couldn't find one which does automatically check the database and has some kind of animation for new updates.

code of the index.php:

```
<body id="scrolling-list">

<div id="wrapper">
<script type="text/javascript"> refreshdiv(); </script>
<div id="timediv">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var t = 0;

$(function() {
 var h = $('#u10').height();
 var lih = $('#u10 li:last').outerHeight();
 var mb = $('#u10 li:last').css('margin-bottom');
 mb = parseInt(mb.substr(0, mb.length - 2));

$('#btn6').click(function() {
  smoothAdd('u10', '<?php echo $team; ?>');
});
});


function smoothAdd(id, text)
{
$('#u10').css('overflow', 'hidden');

var h = $('#u10').height();

var ulPaddingTop = $('#u10').css('padding-top');
ulPaddingTop = ulPaddingTop.substr(0, ulPaddingTop.length - 2);

var ulPaddingBottom = $('#u10').css('padding-bottom');
ulPaddingBottom = ulPaddingBottom.substr(0, ulPaddingBottom.length - 2);

$('#u10').css('height', h);

$('#u10').prepend('<li>' + text + '</li>');

var heightDiff = $('#u10 li:first').outerHeight() - $('#u10 li:last').outerHeight();

var oldMarginTop = $('#u10 li:first').css('margin-top');

$('#u10 li:first').css('margin-top', 0 - $('#u10 li:first').outerHeight());

$('#u10 li:first').css('position', 'relative');
$('#u10 li:first').css('top', 0 - ulPaddingTop);

$('#u10 li:last').css('position', 'relative');

$('#u10').animate({height: h + heightDiff}, 1500)

$('#u10 li:first').animate({top: 0}, 250, function() {
    $('#u10 li:first').animate({marginTop: oldMarginTop}, 1000, function() {
        $('#u10 li:last').animate({top: ulPaddingBottom}, 250, function() {
            $('#u10 li:last').remove();
            $('#u10').css('height', 'auto');
            $('#u10').css('overflow', 'visible');
        });
    });
});
}
</script>

<ul id="u10" class="example">
<li>Item one</li>
<li>Item two</li>
</ul>
```

---

code of the ajax.js

```
var seconds = 5;
var divid = "timediv";
var url = "boo.php";

function refreshdiv(){

// The XMLHttpRequest object

var xmlHttp;
try{
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e){
alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
return false;
}
}
}

// Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request

fetch_unix_timestamp = function()
{
return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
}

var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;

// The code...

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
}
xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

// Start the refreshing process

var seconds;
window.onload = function startrefresh(){
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
```

---

code of boo.php:

```
...
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Return the results, loop through them and echo

echo "<ul class=\"scroller\">";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{ ?>

<li><?php echo $row['team'] . " " . $row['action'];?></li>


<?php } 

echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: can you plz paste your code here?

Comment: Do you have a mechanism to determine which records are "new"? The "Refreshing DIV content with AJAX" article by Aleix Cortadellas replaces the *entire* content of the div / panel, but wouldn't you want to only add the new content, instead of completely replacing it? In which case you'd want a rather different pattern.

Comment: ok i added the code, or at least the important parts. yes, i determine the latest entries by the ID. after the animation and everything works, i will add some if statements to check, if the entry is new